# sequence genration

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, lebesgue-measure

I am having difficulty -normalizing sequence $1,x,x^3$ in $L^2([-1,0]\cup[1,2],dx)$
So I begin by choosing basis $1,x,x^2...$ and i need to use Gram-Schmidt? or how should i approach this?
I have attempted to integrate x from -1 to 0 and add integral from 1 to 2, but I don't think I understand the problem

Comment: What if I am l am looking for a sequence  1, x , $x^3$, I set my $u_0=1$ then find $u_1$ via the method you describe . But what happens with $x^3$ In the summation do I skip 2? and sum from 0, 1, 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_n = x^n$ for $n=0,1,2,\ldots$. Define $u_1=f_1$ and $$u_{n+1} = f_{n+1} - \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\langle f_{n+1},f_k\rangle}{\langle f_k,f_k\rangle}f_k,$$ where
$$\langle f,g\rangle = \int_{[-1,0]\cup[1,2]}f(x)g(x)\ \mathsf dx. $$
Then $\{u_n\}$ is an orthogonal sequence ($\langle u_i,u_j\rangle=0$ for $i\ne j$) with the span of $\{u_0, \ldots, u_n\}$ equal to the span of $\{f_0,\ldots, f_n\}$. To normalize, set
$$e_n = \frac{u_n}{\|f_n\|_2} $$
where $$\|f\|_2 = \int_{[-1,0]\cup[1,2]}f(x)^2\ \mathsf dx. $$
For example,
$$u_2 = x - \frac{\int_{-1}^0 x\ \mathsf dx + \int_{1}^2 x\ \mathsf dx}{\int_{-1}^0  \mathsf dx + \int_{-1}^0 \mathsf dx}\cdot 1 = x-\frac12, $$
and 
$$\|u_2\|_2 = \int_{-1}^0 \left(x-\frac12\right)^2\ \mathsf dx + \int_{1}^2 \left(x-\frac12\right)^2\ \mathsf dx = \frac{13}6, $$
so 
$$e_2 = \frac6{13}\left(x-\frac12\right). $$

Comment: What if I am l am looking for a sequence $1, x ,x^3$ I set my $u_0=1$ then find$ u1$ via the method you describe . But what happens with $x^3$ In the summation do I skip 2? and sum from 0, 1, 3?

Comment: If $x^2$ isn't an element in the set, then you wouldn't include it.

Comment: When I attempt to do it for $x^3$ I get division by zero for denominator...$${\int_{-1}^0  \mathsf x-\frac{1}{2} dx + \int_{1}^2 \mathsf x-\frac{1}{2} dx}\cdot 1 = 0$$

Comment: $$u_3 = x -  \frac{1}{2}- \frac{\int_{-1}^0 \ \mathsf x^4 -\frac{1}{2} x^3dx + \int_{1}^2 \ x^4 -\frac{1}{2} x^3 \mathsf dx}{\int_{-1}^0  \mathsf x-\frac{1}{2} dx + \int_{1}^2 \mathsf x-\frac{1}{2} dx}\cdot x $$